# Error when receiving post from libwww-perl to IIS / ASP.NET

Tags: .net, perl, iis, libwww-perl

I'm trying to recieve a post from a web service to a URL on IIS 7.5. It's like the request is being rejected before it even gets to .NET. I've tried it with an ASP.NET MVC action or a pure .ASPX file.

This is the request coming through:

```
2012-11-29 01:52:40 W3SVC9 Server-Name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx POST /posttest.aspx - 443 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1 libwww-perl/5.837 - - site.com 500 0 0 6357 1226 343
```

Now 6357 is a sc-win32-status code. But it doesn't exist on this page:

[IIS sc-win32-status codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223446/iis-sc-win32-status-codes)

Is there a problem of requests coming from libwww-perl to IIS?

Is there a header missing or something that IIS is being fussy about?

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error indicates that the web server had a problem executing the "program".

I would be looking for the server error logs.